# FILE_FLAG_NO_BUFFERING with overlapped I/O - bytes read zero

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, file-io

I observe a weird behavior while using the flag FILE_FLAG_NO_BUFFERING with overlapped I/O.
I invoke a series of ReadFile() function calls and query their statuses later using GetOverlappedResult().

The weird behavior that I am speaking of is that even though file handles were good and ReadFile() calls returned without any bad error(except ERROR_IO_PENDING which is expected), the 'bytes read' value returned from GetOverlappedResult() call is zero for some of the files, and each time I run the code - it is a different set of files.
**If I remove the FILE_FLAG_NO_BUFFERING, things start working properly and no bytes read value is zero.**

Here is how I have implemented overlapped I/O code with FILE_FLAG_NO_BUFFERING.

```
long overlappedIO(std::vector<std::string> &filePathNameVectorRef)
{    
    long totalBytesRead = 0;
    DWORD bytesRead = 0;
    DWORD bytesToRead = 0;
    std::map<HANDLE, OVERLAPPED> handleMap;
    HANDLE handle = INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE;
    DWORD accessMode = GENERIC_READ;
    DWORD shareMode = 0;
    DWORD createDisposition = OPEN_EXISTING;
    DWORD flags = FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED | FILE_FLAG_NO_BUFFERING;

    DWORD fileSize;
    LARGE_INTEGER li;
    char * buffer;
    BOOL success = false;

    for(unsigned int i=0; i<filePathNameVectorRef.size(); i++)
    {
        const char* filePathName = filePathNameVectorRef[i].c_str();

        handle = CreateFile(filePathName, accessMode, shareMode, NULL, createDisposition, flags, NULL);

        if(handle == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE){
            fprintf(stdout, "\n Error occured: %d", GetLastError());
            fprintf(stdout," getting handle: %s",filePathName);
            continue;
        }
        GetFileSizeEx(handle, &li);
        fileSize = (DWORD)li.QuadPart;

        bytesToRead = (fileSize/g_bytesPerPhysicalSector)*g_bytesPerPhysicalSector;
        buffer = static_cast<char *>(VirtualAlloc(0, bytesToRead, MEM_COMMIT, PAGE_READWRITE));

        OVERLAPPED overlapped;
        ZeroMemory(&overlapped, sizeof(overlapped));
        OVERLAPPED * lpOverlapped = &overlapped;

        success = ReadFile(handle, buffer, bytesToRead, &bytesRead, lpOverlapped);

        if(!success && GetLastError() != ERROR_IO_PENDING){ 
            fprintf(stdout, "\n Error occured: %d", GetLastError());
            fprintf(stdout, "\n reading file %s",filePathName);
            CloseHandle(handle);
            continue;
        }
        else
            handleMap[handle] = overlapped;
    }

    // Status check and bytes Read value
    for(std::map<HANDLE, OVERLAPPED>::iterator iter = handleMap.begin(); iter != handleMap.end(); iter++)
    {
        HANDLE handle = iter->first;        
        OVERLAPPED * overlappedPtr = &(iter->second);

        success = GetOverlappedResult(handle, overlappedPtr, &bytesRead, TRUE);
        if(success)
        {
                /* bytesRead value in some cases is unexpectedly zero */
                /* no file is of size zero or lesser than 512 bytes(physical volume sector size) */
            totalBytesRead += bytesRead;
            CloseHandle(handle);
        }
    }

    return totalBytesRead;
}
```

With FILE_FLAG_NO_BUFFERING absent, totalBytesRead value is 57 MB. With the flag present, totalBytesRead value is much lower than 57 MB and keeps changing each time I run the code ranging from 2 MB to 15 MB.

Comment: Your approach to the OVERLAPPED structures is wrong.  You are passing the address of a stack variable that goes out of scope.  Change your map to hold pointers to OVERLAPPED structures and allocate them on the heap instead.  Also, the 4th parameter to your first ReadFile() call should be NULL for overlapped I/O.

Comment: It doesn't go out of scope.  But it is certainly wrong, every ReadFile() will use the same one.  That cannot work.  It is also fairly doubtful that this will actually improve anything, overlapped I/O only makes sense if you don't wait for it to complete.  Whether the file system can take advantage of multiple overlaps is a long distance shot.

Answer (score 1):

Your calculation of bytesToRead will produce 0 as a result when the file size is less than g_bytesPerPhysicalSector. So for small files you are requesting 0 bytes.